# If Heap is dynamic then why it is placed in between stack and data area

Tags: linux, memory-management, operating-system, heap-memory, stack-memory

I am currently learning about Operating systems and got struck at this.

- If the size of Heap area is dynamic then why it is placed  at the bottom of the stack.
- If size of the heap increase will the stack's start memory (MAX_SIZE in the image) also increase to a higher address to accommodate space for the heap or it is limited to use the space in between stack and data area.

[image: Memory layout]

PS: I searched for this in online but didn't find what I am looking for.

Comment: There is no higher address that is available. See "MAX" in the image: it is the end of the memory that is available to the process. If heap and stack memory have consumed all free memory, then that is an out-of-memory condition.

Comment: No matter where you put it, it will eventually run into some other memory area or the end of memory.

Comment: The blue area in the pic between the heap and stack is not mapped to any physical memory until it is allocated by the program, or possibly not until the process reads from or writes to it.  Since the stack grows downward, placing it at the very top of the process's address space makes sense.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the diagram. Both heap and stack grow dynamically. The heap grows up, the stack grows down. If they run into each other you're out of memory.

Comment: That's also a very naive view. It is not going to be that simple as in the diagram on a modern operating system. In particular modern operating systems try to randomize the addresses of stack, heap and other segments for security reasons. Also, the "heap" as shown is only a small part of the memory used for dynamic allocation, implemented with the `sbrk` syscall on linux. Larger memory areas are obtained with e.g. `mmap` on linux. And you don't really need to care about the location of stack/heap for writing your program.

Answer (score 0):

The stack is given a fixed size by the os. When compiling, instructions use up stack and the stack memory usage is already known during compilation. For example, if you enter a function that has 2 64 bits variables then the compiler reserves 8 bytes of stack by generating access instructions such as `mov STACK_POINTER, SOME_DATA` or `mov STACK_POINTER - 8, SOME_DATA` or vice-versa. What determines the position of the stack in virtual memory is just the value chosen by the os for STACK_POINTER.

The amount of stack used by a particular function is already known so it is your job to make sure the stack isn't overly used because it has a limited size.

For the heap, accesses are absolute and the address dynamically chosen by the os by looking at available virtual memory pages. In terms of cpu instructions, it is just a register chosen to store the return of a syscall made to the os. The application makes a syscall and, when the syscall returns, further instructions in the program assume that the corresponding register contains an available address for data storage or, potentially, an error code.

Since paging is used, the virtual address space has hundreds of thousands of GB available. In terms of how much data you can allocate, it depends on how much of the association of virtual memory to physical memory can be defered. As long as you don't actually write dynamic (heap) virtual memory, the os doesn't even have to associate the region (the page) with a physical location. This is because that region of memory wasn't modified so it doesn't contain anything of value to keep track of. The os can thus defer its association with physical memory as long as it doesn't contain something of value. Once it does, the os has to keep it somewhere (RAM or SWAP). It is thus safe to say that, when you have more than ram + swap of initialized/valuable data, the os has run out of space and might react by refusing further allocations, terminating an application, or other.

In summary, the virtual address space is so big that the os runs out of space much before the heap meets the stack. If it does, then your computer already ran out of space thousands of times and the os doesn't let you go there.